# How to handle $0 dollar transactions

Tags: magento, authorize.net, payment-processing

My store offers some `100%` off coupons, including shipping.  When I try to checkout, it asks for my credit card information.  When I try to place the order, it comes back saying `"Invalid amount for authorization"`.  I'm using **Authorize.net**.

Any ideas?

Comment: FYI, Magento now has its own StackExchange site: http://magento.stackexchange.com

Comment: how can ebay siphon payments if there is no charge??

Comment: You can use zero subtotal checkout payment method  for that case....it will be the better option

Comment: Thats Correct Amit. You cannot do a $0 trans with Mage as it's built in the core for an amt. Use the Zero subtotal checkout option for credit card verifications